# CSV Parsing Python, outputting certain rows that have an specific value

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing

I want to use python to parse a CSV file, and output only certain rows which have a specific value. This is the code I have until now,

```
import csv  

f = open('alerts2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
li1 = []
header = next(csv_f)
for row in csv_f:

    # li1.append(row[5])
    # li1.append(row[0]) 
    severity = int(row[0]) #Has The the integer value from 10 - 40
    Status = str(row[1])
    PolicyName = str(row[2])
    PolicyBlockName = str(row[3])
    PolicyRuleName = str(row[4])
    Summary = str(row[5])
    li1.append(severity)
    li1.append(Summary) # string variables
print li1
f.close()
```

This outputs all the values from severity and summary, but I want it to output the data of severity and summary only if the severity value is at "10" . 
I was thinking to use the list "li1" and search through the list and if the value "10" is found then output the values.  Any suggestions?? I am a python newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this check to your loop over the csv rows:

```
for row in csv_f:
    severity = int(row[0])
    if severity != 10:
        continue
```

if the `severity` value is not 10 the loop will `continue` with the next row and not do anything that follows for the current row.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain your solution a little bit more. Thanks.

Comment: the python documentation has a section on [continue statements in for loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

alerts_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('alerts2.csv', index_col=None)
print alerts_df[alerts_df['severity'] == 10]['Summary']
```